# Accessing variable from within ParseQuery [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am having trouble accessing the variable retrieved from parse outside of the actual parse query . It tells me that it cannot assign a value to final variable.

```
    final String startTime;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> startQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockIn");
    startQuery.getInBackground(clockInId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject clockIn, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                startTime = clockIn.getString("Time");
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    });

    //Retrieve clockOutId (ObjectID for clockOutTime)
    final String endTime;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> endQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockOut");
    endQuery.getInBackground(clockOutId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject clockOut, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                endTime = clockOut.getString("Time");
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    });
```

I need to access endTime and startTime and then take the difference but it tells me the variables haven't been initialized due to the final issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"final" variables can't be modified, you can declare those variables at the beginning of your class and then assign the value.

Try this...

```
public class YourActivityOrWhatYouNeed{
    String startTime="";
    String endTime="";
    ...
    ...
    ...


ParseQuery<ParseObject> startQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockIn");
startQuery.getInBackground(clockInId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject clockIn, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            startTime = clockIn.getString("Time");
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
});

//Retrieve clockOutId (ObjectID for clockOutTime)
ParseQuery<ParseObject> endQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("clockOut");
endQuery.getInBackground(clockOutId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject clockOut, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            endTime = clockOut.getString("Time");
        } else {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Will try this out when I get to the house , thanks !

Comment: Variable startTIme & endTime say they are never used and within the if statement it says they cannot be resolved. Any ideas ? This is within a method of its own .

Comment: My mistake . Was writing the code in the wrong spot. Thanks again!